# Execute an intent whatever the user response on dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

Is it possible to execute a specific intent whatever the user response is? I know the "follow-up" but this doesn't wait for the user response to execute the intent.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the "[Fallback Intent](https://dialogflow.com/docs/intents#fallback_intents)", which is the Intent that gets matched when no other Intents do.

If you want to capture all responses after you prompt something, set an outgoing [Context](https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts) in the Intent that does the prompt and then create a Fallback Intent that has that as an incoming Context.